# Using subprocess pipes in seperate files

Tags: python, module, subprocess, pipe

I have a .py script which contains code that opens a subprocess and creates stdin and stdout Pipes within that subprocess. The code which does that is as follows:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='"8-bit" Zip Sim')
    parser.add_argument('pilot', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER, help='A pilot process to run')
    parser.add_argument('--headless', action="store_true", help='Run without visualization')
    visualizer_group = parser.add_argument_group("Visualization options")
    visualizer_group.add_argument('--chase-y', action="store_true", help='Have the camera follow the zip in the y axis')
    visualizer_group.add_argument('--show-lidar', action="store_true", help='Shows lidar in the visualization')
    visualizer_group.add_argument('--start-paused', action="store_true", help='Start the simulation paused')
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, help='Seed to use for random number generation')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    random.seed(args.seed)
    headless = args.headless
    api_mode = len(args.pilot) > 0
    
 
    
    if api_mode:
        pilot = subprocess.Popen(args.pilot, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        loop_count = 0  # To count iterations to compute the telemetry timestamp
```

Now we can say that Pilot is a subprocess with the stdin/stdout pipes open. I would like to create a seperate .py script which connects to these pipes. The first .py file (that contain the above code) writes and reads from stdin and stdout respectively. This is the code that writes to stdin, and reads from stdout:

```
    lidar_samples = cast_lidar(vehicle.position, lidar_objects)
    pilot.stdin.write(TELEMETRY_STRUCT.pack(int(loop_count * DT_SEC * 1e3) & 0xFFFF,
                                            round(RECOVERY_X - vehicle.position[0]),
                                            wind.vector[0],
                                            wind.vector[1],
                                            round((-vehicle.position[1] + WORLD_WIDTH_HALF) % 
                                                  WORLD_WIDTH -
                                                  WORLD_WIDTH_HALF),
                                            *lidar_samples))
    #pilot.stdin.flush()
    loop_count += 1
    cmd = pilot.stdout.read(COMMAND_STRUCT.size)
```

In my separate .py script, I want to write to the stdout Pipe and read from the stdin pipe. That way, I will be able to read the TELEMETRY STRUCT in my separate .py script and be able to communicate to the cmd variable above. Does anyone know how to do this? Do I have to create a subprocess in my separate .py script?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your `subprocess` uses pipe to communicate with `main process` and it can't use it to communicate with other proces/program. You can only use pipe to communicate with current `main process` using `python script2.py | python script1.py` - it needs only `print()` and `input()`

Comment: If you want to pipe data to another script, one way of doing it is from the shell: `python script1.py | python script2.py` - anything that script 1 writes to `sys.stdout` can be read by script 2 on `sys.stdin`. Of course, if you must, you could make that call from a third script, but at that point you should consider looking at `subprocess` and `Queue()` instead

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I am currently opening my shell and running the command python s1.py python s2.py. However, I can't read anything from script 1 (the script I posted above). Am I supposed to set up something in script 2 to be able to do that. I have noticed that if i print something using print() in script 2 then script 1 can read it

Comment: I guess my question is how do I read what script 1 is writing to stdin using script 2, and how do I write to stdout in script 2 so that script 1 can read it